# Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI x86 to copy into the AVD folder

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-2.2-froyo

I am getting error as :
**Error: Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI x86 to copy into the AVD folder.**

I have checked almost all the threads on internet and that include all stackoverflow threads for the topic but of no use.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Platform : Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the location for System image to be used by Android SDK Manager and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Intel x86 System Image for your API version in Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Well the issue is that i have added the required System image. I tried solving the issue and finally it boils down that the location of System images changes in android-sdk and it was looking at incorrect location for the image.

Comment: I have this same issue. `android` reports I have many images installed but `android avd` cannot ever find the images when I make a new device. How did you solve this?